# using the standard input stream leads to compilation failure

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

Running simple c++ program (e.g. HelloWorld) has no problem, but when I use cin in my code, I see the following error

> procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located in the
>   dynamic link library C:\Users\username\Desktop\helloworld.exe

I use MinGW compiler, sublime text on windows 10

---

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you haven't included any code, I'm forced to consult my crystal ball, which says the error is on line 42. The Ouija board says there's probably either a `c` or an `h` in the extension of the file name.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Crystal balls never lie.

Comment: If you actually *run*  your program to get the error, it's not a compiler error. It's not a linker error either in that case.

Comment: Here's my code

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 int x = 1;
 cin >> x;
 cout << x << endl;
 return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

From this archive in gcc mailing list https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2002-07/msg00186.html,

> `__gxx_personality_v0` is part of the G++ exception handling model defined
>   by the new C++ ABI in GCC.  The symbol is provided by the `libstdc++`
>   library, which is added to the link line by g++.

So, in this case, I'm pretty sure that you used `mingw-gcc` to compile your code. Switch to `mingw-g++` or add `-lstdc++` to your command will make the job done.

Comment: I use this command to run cpp file
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld.exe